# 1 $\%$ of 200 $\%$ of $360$ is what percent of $0.1 \%$ of $60$?

Tags: percentages

1 $\%$ of 200 $\%$ of $360$ is what percent of $0.1 \%$ of $60$?

---

1 $\%$ of 200 $\%$ of $360$ is what percent of $0.1 \%$ of $60$?

$\dfrac{1}{100}\dfrac{200}{100}360=y/100\dfrac{0.1}{100}60$

$y/100=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{100}\dfrac{200}{100}360*100}{0.1*60}$

$y/100=\dfrac{720}{6} \implies y/100= 120$

$y$ is $12000 \iff \dfrac{y}{100} is 12000 \%$.

---

A calculator tells me the answer to 1 $\%$ of 200 $\%$ of $360$ is what percent of $0.1 \%$ of $60$? is $12000\%$

---

Comment: What happened to the "/100" in your last step?

Comment: $y/100 = 120$, so $y$ is...?

Comment: y=12000 percent means y=12000/100 means y=120.

Comment: It's $y=12000$, not $y=12000\%$.

Comment: $7.2$ is $120$ times $0.06$ or $7.2$ is $12000\%$ of $0.06$

Comment: Is the question resolved? Either:
$$y = \text{"what"} = 12000\\
y\% = \text{"what percent"} = 12000\%$$

Comment: You need not divide with $100$ in the last step as you have considered y in percent in the frst step